# Refactor `f(g(x))(x)` so that I can compose this nicely

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, lodash, function-composition

I have a couple of functions that currently are written (in abstract form) like this...

```
const someFunction = x => f(g(x))(x);
```

i.e.

1. pass `x` into `g` to get the output.
2. Then pass that output into `f` to get a `function`.
3. And then pass `x` into that `function`.

It feels a bit clunky due to the nested brackets, the real world function names, and multiple uses of `x` etc...

I've been using `lodash/fp` and my first thought was `_.flow` but then I'd still have to pass `x` into the output of the flow in the end.

Hmm... unless I reverse the order of the parameters in `f` then I could do...

```
const someFunction = x => _.flow(g, f(x))(x);
```

I think this would work as `f(x)` would pass `x` into `f` to get the function out. And then this `_.flow(g, f(x))(x)` would pass `x` into `g` and then pass the output of that into the resulting curried function returned from `f`.

It's still clunky though. Not entirely happy with it. Is there another more elegant/more readable way of doing it that could be suggested.

Comment: _"Would that work?"_ - You could just test it instead of asking us to do it for you

Comment: It was more of a rhetorical question to prompt other solutions. I have removed it. I wasn't asking anyone to test it for me. Trigger happy mods closing questions too eagerly. It is still a valid question. 

Comment: 1. Why did you ping me? It requires 3 close votes; 2. _"Is there a nicer way"_ is still not a valid question for SO (imho)

Comment: `_.flow()` is not intended for this case. Create an arrow function and curry it  - `const chain = _.curry((f, g, x) => f(g(x))(x))`

Comment: Your feeling is right, you are on to something. The `f(g(x)) (x)` pattern is actually an instance of one of the most famous patterns in FP. It is the `chain`/`bind`/`flatmap` of the function type, that is one of the terms that are required for a type to form a monad algebra. The applicative version is `f(x) (g(x))`, which is equivalent to the former due to `flip = f => y => x => f(x) (y)`.  However, this doesn't help you much, because there is no monad/applicative support in lodash, AFAIK. You need a fantasy-land compliant lib to get the monad machinery.

Comment: @scriptum this is awesome! I knew there would be something like this that I could use. Is there a particular library that you would recommend for doing something like this? I opted for lodash because I didn't know any others. Or is the "fantasy-land compliant lib" something that doesn't exist?  Thanks

Comment: @OriDrori I got this working thanks. This is so useful for me! Thanks! I use this pattern all over the place and had to change the ways I wrote a lot of the functions to get around this awkward pattern. Using `chain` like this will allow me to fix all of those cases. Thanks 

Comment: We usually don't use the raw function type as a monad instance but resort to a wrapped type called `Reader`. Unfortunately there is no lib I'd recommend. The lads of the fantasyland spec have created an [examplary implementation](https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-readers) though. The thing is monads are not easy, because you cannot use them standalone. They act systemically, i.e. if you ask for a monad you wind up with lots of monad instances for different types and transformers to compose them and I guess that is not what you want..

Comment: @scriptum ah, ok, makes sense. Thanks very much. 

Comment: @OriDrori or Scriptum if you would like to add an answer I'll accept now. Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks to the input from @Ori_Drori I created a function...

```
const chain = _.curry((f, g, x) => f(g(x))(x));
```

And then my code that started out as...

```
const myOldFunction = (x) => f(g(x))(x);
```

turned into...

```
const myAwesomeNewFunction = chain(f, g);
```

Which made it much more readable and turned it into a function with a single input which meant I could make it point free and then put it into the rest of my functions really nicely.